# How to get website generated data to excel

Tags: excel, vba

Do you have any idea how to get this little table from this [website](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/quota_consultation.jsp?Lang=en&Origin=&Code=096714&Year=2019&Critical=&Status=&Expand=true) to excel?

Normal source code scraping won't work since the results are not stored in the source. Power query doesn't work either...

Edit:

I have tried Power Query. I have some codes that download data from websites searching by class, tag etc. - but all of them search in the source, not in the rendered website, so posting such codes, just to post anything, is pointless.

Comment: if you're seeking help with your vba, please [edit] your question to *include your code* and an explanation of what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and specifically where you're having a problem.  (See [mcve] as well as "[ask]".)  Good luck!

Comment: Mikku, the point is I have a code that gets this data from source code, and since this data is NOT in the source code, nor it is 'query downloadable', it's pointless to even post such code. I'm just asking if it is even possible with VBA, if yes then I can write a code and come back if it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that starting off with web scraping can be sometimes cumbersome and the volume of information out there can be overwhelming so I decided to kickstart your efforts in the hopes that in the future you will at least know where to start from.

1. **Inspect the network traffic.**

Use your browser's developer tools to inspect the requests being sent when you browse a website. In your case, the requests that are sent under the hood when you press search are quite a few. However, you only need one of them. It's the `XHR` request that produces the table as a response.

[image]

2. **Inspect the request itself**

The request basically consists of a URL which contains the parameters that you select in the dropdown menus, the headers which in your case are not essential to the result and a body which in your case is empty because all the parameters are contained in the URL.

[image]

3. **Inspect the response**

The response in your case is an HTML. It could have been something else like a JSON. The data you want is in an HTML table with an ID "qoutaTable".

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Including version.html for defect CUSTD00035918 Start -->
  <meta name="application" content="DDS2-TARIC" />
  <meta name="version" content="@REL@" />

  <!-- Defect# CUSTD00024730 Start -->
  <!-- IPG Rule requires the following 7 metatags in all application pages. Additional metatags e.g. version and application can be added if required by the application. -->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en">
  <meta name="description" content="DDS2-TARIC Application page">
  <meta name="reference" content="DDS2-TARIC Reference">
  <meta name="creator" content="DG-TAXUD">
  <meta name="classification" content="DDS2-TARIC">
  <meta name="keywords" content="DDS2-TARIC, TARIC, DDS2">
  <meta name="date" content="">
  <!-- Defect# CUSTD00024730 End -->
  <!-- Including version.html for defect CUSTD00035918 End -->
</head>



<body style="background-color:#FFFFF0;">












  <div id="quotaMarkedUpContainer">

    <div class='scroller' id="navigation" align=center>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>

          </td>


          <td>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <table id="quotaTable" class="list" width="100%" style="padding-left: 7%; padding-right: 7%;">

      <thead>
        <tr class="columnHeader">
          <th>
            Order number
          </th>
          <th>
            Origins
          </th>
          <th style="text-align: center;">
            Start date
          </th>
          <th style="text-align: center;">
            End date
          </th>
          <th style="text-align: right;">
            Balance
          </th>
          <th/>
        </tr>
      </thead>










      <tr class="oddRow">

        <td>
          096714
        </td>
        <td>






          <div>
            Ukraine
          </div>


        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          01-01-2019
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          31-12-2019
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">

          0&nbsp; Kilogram


        </td>
        <td>

          <a id="quotaLink" href="https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/quota_tariff_details.jsp?Lang=en&StartDate=2019-01-01&Code=096714" style="color:#3247e8; text-decoration:underline;" class='browse_action_a'>[More info]</a>


        </td>
      </tr>



    </table>

    <div class='scroller' id="navigation" align=center>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>

          </td>


          <td>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>





</body>

</html>
```

4. **Write the code**

For that you will need the following references

- Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1 (to create and manipulate HTTP requests)
- Microsoft HTML Object Library (to manipulate HTML elements)

Here's an example of how to get one of the table's cells:

```
Option Explicit
Sub getData()
Dim req As New WinHttpRequest
Dim doc As New HTMLDocument
Dim table As HTMLTable
Dim url As String, code As String, year As String, origin As String, status As String, critical As String 'the request's parameters

critical = "" 'you can leave it blank if it's not important to your search
status = "" 'you can leave it blank if it's not important to your search
origin = "UA"
year = "2019"
code = "096714"
url = "https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/quota_list.jsp?Lang=en&Origin=" & origin & "&Code=" & code & "&Year=" & year & "&Status=" & status & "&Critical=" & critical & "&Expand=true&Offset=0" 'build the URL by concatenating the various parameters

With req
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .send
    doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText 'Assign the HTML response to an HTML document object
    'Debug.Print .responseText
End With
Set table = doc.getElementById("quotaTable") 'get the table you're interested in
Debug.Print table.Rows(1).Cells(4).innerText 'print the 5th cell of the 2nd row in the immediate window
End Sub
```

The result looks like that:

[image]

For demonstration purposes I'm only showing you how to print the contents of one of the table's cells. You can experiment with the above code and modify it to get access to the other elements of the table as well.

Comment: Works like a charm! Do you have a solution to excel visible range being resized after using this code?

Answer (score 0):

I use Chrome and have the result stored in the source. Then I simply copy the html code to the online html to csv:

[Html to csv online editor](http://www.convertcsv.com/html-table-to-csv.htm)

It works for me. Or if this is not your solution please try to describe better your problem.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, this table is not stored in the source. If it was in html you do not have to copy it anywhere since you can download source directly via vba.